# Incorrect date displayed with ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, time

I am working on a site that is using version 2.6 of the Esri JavaScript API.  I have an info window that displays some date information, and the date is one day behind the date in the database.

For example:

If I identify a feature in ArcMap, the date returned is 8/15/2007.
When I query for the same feature through the Rest endpoint I get 2007/08/15 00:00:00 UTC.
When I identify the feature in the web application, the date returned is 8/14/2007.

In the JavaScript code I am formatting the date as follows:

```
${SALEDT:DateFormat(selector: 'date', fullYear: true)}
```

What is causing this, and what can I do to have the correct date returned?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specify local: true in your date formatting function:

```
${SALEDT:DateFormat(selector: 'date', local: true, fullYear: true)}
```

[Mintx's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/20317/124) explains why you need to do this. More information on formatting info window/popup content is available in the help:  [Format info window content](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jshelp/intro_formatinfowindow.htm).

**Edit:**  Use DateString, not DateFormat to specify the local option:

```
${SALEDT:DateString(local: true, hideTime: true)}
```

**Edit 2:**  Thanks to the mods, here's the answer originally posted my Mintx that I refereced above:

> You've got it mostly right, you just need to change the code to
>   reflect the correct time zone.
>        Since the feature you're reading from is a UTC timestamp, the JavaScript code is converting to your timezone, which (assuming you're
>   in the US) will be 4 to 7 hours earlier than midnight of 8/15/2007,
>   which is why it's returning one day earlier.

**Edit 3:**  I threw together a quick, hacky way to do this with a custom formatting function: [jsfiddle.net/yEkjm](http://jsfiddle.net/yEkjm) There is probably a better way to do this...I'm no expert on handling dates with JS.

Comment: Thanks Derek.  I put local: true in the formatting function and am still getting dates one day behind.  I verified that I have dojo.require("dojo.date.locale") - is there anything else I need?  I verified that the setting/code isn't being cached.

Comment: That's my mistake, I used DateFormat in my answer and it should be DateString. I've edited my answer to show the correct syntax.

Comment: I tried using DateString earlier today, but I need the date in mm/dd/yyyy format, and DateString returns the date as "Tue August 14 2007."

Comment: @Tim if you want fine grained control over the date format, we're back to DateFormat. In my testing, features retrieved from a service that stores dates as UTC are automatically converted to the client's timezone when displayed.

Comment: Thanks Derek.  You're right, they are being converted to my time zone - that's why they're one day earlier.  Is there a way to force the dates to be returned as UTC, since that date is the correct one?

Comment: @Tim I threw together a quick, hacky way to do this with a custom formatting function:  http://jsfiddle.net/yEkjm/ There is probably a better way to do this...I'm no expert on handling dates with JS.

Comment: Thanks!  That's close to what I was trying to put together.  I just tested it with my app and it appears to be returning the correct date.  Can you add that solution to your answer and I will mark it as accepted?

Comment: @Tim edited my answer, again :).